# ошибка при попытке скачать пакеты

Tags: flutter

Running "flutter pub get" in exam...
Превышен таймаут семафора.
(OS Error: Превышен таймаут семафора.
, errno = 121), address = pub.dartlang.org, port = 53074
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение.
(OS Error: Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение.
, errno = 1225), address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 53213
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение.
(OS Error: Удаленный компьютер отклонил это сетевое подключение.
, errno = 1225), address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 53356
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте скачать пакеты с помощью VPN. Похоже, что ваша сеть блокирует это подключение.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).